# C program without #include<stdio.h> in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

When I create a simple C program in Visual Studio 2010, 
http://debugmode.net/2012/02/06/how-to-write-and-run-a-c-program-in-visual-studio-2010/

I remove the "#include < stdio.h > ",

My program still runs successfully, I could not understand how is it possible?

Any help is appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: Please don't follow their habit of using `void main`.

Comment: When I ride my bicycle fast enough and take my hands on the handlebars, it travels in a straight line. However, that doesn't make it a good idea :-)

Answer (score 2):

The stdio.h header isn't strictly required unless you use functions declared in it, such as the following:

http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html

Further looking at the code I believe the default behaviour when you don't have a prototype is to assume an int return type and to derive the types of parameters from the types of arguments which will work in this particular case. But it's generally a bad practice and should be avoided.

If that passed through the compiler / linker without any warnings you may want to check your environment settings. It's easy to forget to include an header and it can cause a lot of unintended and hard to track down side effects if you don't notice it.

Comment: From what I can tell, it uses `printf`.

Comment: No, when the declaration and/or prototype is missing, the default behavior is to assume `int` return type and to derive the types of parameters from the types of arguments. For a string literal, the compiler has to derive that the parameter has type `char *`, not `int`. However, with `printf` there is a different problem. `printf` is a variadic function. If a variadic function is called without a prototype, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The primary purpose of including standard header files is to include the declarations of standard functions into your source file.

However, the original standard C language (C89/90) did not require functions to be declared before they are called (aside from variadic functions, which have to be pre-declared with prototype to avoid undefined behavior). For this reason, as long as we are talking about non-variadic function calls, it is perfectly possible to write a correct program without pre-declaring standard functions, i.e. without including standard header files.

For example, calling `strcmp` function with two `char *` arguments is perfectly legal in C89/90 without pre-declaring `strcmp`. Meanwhile, `printf` has to be pre-declared with prototype, if you want your program to remain a valid C program with defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This header file provides prototypes for a number of common functions and macros.

If you don't call any of those functions or macros, then you don't need it. If you do call them, it can still work as long as you are linking with the right libraries. But you could get some compiler errors or warnings if the compiler doesn't have those definitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include < stdio.h >
```

It is a header file known as **standard input output file**. The input,output funcation are written in this file. funcations like `printf,scanf` etc. 
 Refere this http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c2.htm

Comment: FWIW, while your answer has the most direct answer as to what stdio.h is, that's not what the OP was getting at.  His question was why the include directive for stdio.h can be omitted, implying he has at least a working idea of what stdio.h does.